# TLS1.2 still used despite forcing use of TLS1.0

Tags: ftp, curl, tls

I have a customer who is trying to connect to my company's FTP server and we have asked him to force the use of TLS1.0, which he has done through a curl request (curl version : 7.29.0). However, despite the latest version of curl and the forcing of tls1.0, the connection is still using tls1.2.

Do you know why this is happening? I was wondering if maybe this was due to both protocols using different ports? Our last solution would be to ask our security or system team to review the FTP server's configuration to allow connection from tls1.0 but we would like to avoid it.

Thank you in advance for your help and let me know if something remains unclear, I can potentially provide with the output

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why TLS 1.0? Your use-case is unclear.  It's been on the 'please stop using this' list for many years & most of the majors finally forced its EoL last year. TLS 1.0 is 1999 spec, surpassed even by TLS 1.2 in 2008. Even WinXP could use TLS 1.2. There is no excuse to still be using it these days.

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense. Why would you need your security team to allow TLS 1.0 when you're actively encouring him to use TLS 1.0? What commandline parameters did you use to force TLS 1.0 and how did you verify what the problem is? CURL 7.29 was released back in 2013 and didn't have support for `--tls-max`.

Answer (score 0):

The [curl manpage](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html) states:

> --tlsv1.0
>
> (TLS) Forces curl to use TLS version 1.0 or later when connecting to a remote TLS server.
>
> In old versions of curl this option was documented to allow *only* TLS 1.0. That behavior was inconsistent depending on the TLS library. Use --tls-max if you want to set a maximum TLS version.

> --tls-max
>
> (SSL) VERSION defines maximum supported TLS version. The minimum acceptable version is set by tlsv1.0, tlsv1.1, tlsv1.2 or tlsv1.3.
>
> If the connection is done without TLS, this option has no effect. This includes QUIC-using (HTTP/3) transfers.
>
> See also --tlsv1.0, --tlsv1.1, --tlsv1.2 and --tlsv1.3. --tls-max requires that the underlying libcurl was built to support TLS. Added in 7.54.0.

If that customer is really using such an outdated CURL version it might just not have support to force TLS 1.0.